# AFNetworking parse error when no content

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking to connect with API.

I have many request with json response.

In one case response is no content and I have go error serialization response.

```
self.manger.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [self.manger.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:15];

    [self.manger POST:URL parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        success(responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        fail(operation,error);
        NSLog(@"error code %d",[[[error userInfo] objectForKey:AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey] statusCode]);

    }];
```

Comment: Poor design of API. If you don't care to send { ok: true } back maybe you shouldn't use JSON serialization or simply use HEAD request.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change server response (like Andy said, if you are expecting JSON response, server should reply with JSON), try to set response serializer to "standard" serializer, something like:

```
self.manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```